# Using column variables in my WHERE clause

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I have two tables (tableA and tableB) both with a name column. tableA's name column might be called NAME, tableB's column might be called FULLNAME, but they both are supposed to have the same value.

I am to write a query that pulls member id's (from either table) where these two column values are not the same. However, I'd like to pass the column names I'm checking via parameter, as this will be going in an SSRS report and in the future i'd like to be able to use it to compare any other column between these two tables.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @COLUMN_A VARCHAR(50), @COLUMN_B VARCHAR(50)

/* COLUMN PARAMS WILL BE PASSED IN VIA SSRS */

SELECT
    DISTINCT(MEMBER_ID)
FROM
    TABLE_A
JOIN TABLE_B
    ON (TABLE_A.MEMBER_ID = TABLE_B.MEMBER_ID)
WHERE
    @COLUMN_A <> @COLUMN_B
```

Is something like this possible?

edit:

Or might something like this work?

DECLARE
@column VARCHAR(50)

```
SELECT @column = 'FIRST_NAME';
SELECT DISTINCT
    MEMBR_ID,
    case    
        when @column='FIRST_NAME' then MEMBR_FIRST_NAME
        when @column='LAST_NAME' then MEMBR_LAST_NAME


    end TABLE_1,
    case
        when @column='FIRST_NAME' then FIRSTNAME
        when @column='LAST_NAME' then LASTNAME
    end TABLE_2,
    @column
FROM 
    TABLE_1
JOIN    TABLE_2
    ON (TABLE_1.MEMBR_ID = TABLE_2.MEMBR_ID)

WHERE  
    TABLE_1.@column <> TABLE_2.@column
```

Comment: Dynamic SQL is your friend

Answer (score 0):

> Is something like this possible?

Technically, the syntax is fine.  The `where` will be comparing two constant strings.  The results will be either all rows or no rows, depending on whether the two strings are the same.

Do these evaluate to the columns?  No, they do not.  You cannot pass parameters into a SQL statement for identifiers -- column names, table names, schema names, database names, function names, or operators (for example).

You can do this using dynamic SQL, but you have to plug the names in:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = '
SELECT DISTINCT A.MEMBER_ID
FROM TABLE_A A JOIN
     TABLE_B B
     ON A.MEMBER_ID = B.MEMBER_ID
WHERE A.@COLUMN_A <> B.@COLUMN_B
';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql '@COLUMN_A', COLUMN_A);
SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql '@COLUMN_B', COLUMN_B);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: thanks, the only problem with that is where you are trying to REPLACE @COLUMN_A and B, it is not recognizing the variable nor the actual column name (3rd arg) as valid column names...

Comment: nevermind I got it, the third argument in REPLACE is supposed to be a string

THANK YOU